# Active ORM/OGM projects for Graph Database?

Tags: python, graph-databases, gremlin-server

I am wondering whether someone knows about any new projects which can map nodes/relationships in a graph DB to objects/references in an object-oriented programming language, like Python. I've found projects such as Bulbs (https://github.com/espeed/bulbs) but this project is several years old and not compatible with the latest versions. Ideally I am looking for something which can work with a graph hosted from or connected to a Gremlin Server instance, that is active and up-to-date with the latest versions of Python/Gremlin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of right now, you're best option is [Goblin](https://github.com/davebshow/goblin).

Comment: Thank you! That was one of the ones I was looking at.